# How to find joint distribution of X,Y?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that $X$ is a uniform random variable in $[-1,1]$ and $Y$ is also a uniform random variable in $[-\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-x^2}]$. how can I find their joint distribution?

Can we use this formula?

$f_{XY}(x,y)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{P[x\leq X\leq x+\epsilon, y\leq Y\leq y+\epsilon]}{\epsilon^2}$

Or are there better ways?

Answer (score 1):

The text gives you the $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{1}_{[-1;1]}(x)$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathbb{1}_{[-\sqrt{1-x^2};\sqrt{1-x^2}]}(y)$

So the joint distribution is simply their product:

$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathbb{1}_{[-\sqrt{1-x^2};\sqrt{1-x^2}]}(y)\mathbb{1}_{[-1;1]}(x)$

In other words, the joint density is defined in the circle $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$